# Cannot access Neo4j browser on a Windows Server

Tags: azure, neo4j, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 virtual machine provisioned on Azure. I installed Neo4j server on this virtual machine and I'm accessing the Neo4j browser on `localhost:7474`.

However I cannot access the browser outside using my virtual machine's public IP `e.g <machineIP:7474>`

Here's what I have done so far:

- In the Azure portal, I added inbound rules for the NSG to allow http and https ports 80 and 443 (I have done the same on a Linux virtual machine also hosted in Azure and I can access the browser just fine)
- I also added an inbound rule in Windows Firewall to allow `Port 80 and 443 as well`

What possibly blocks me from accessing the virtual machine's IP from the outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add TCP port 7474 to the firewall in the Azure portal:

[image: Azure Neo4j]

Comment: In my case not only in the NSG inbound rules but also in the Windows Defender Firewall inbound rules.

Answer (score 1):

change your neo4j-server.properties

set

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I cant find this file. is this the same as `neo4j/conf/neo4j.conf`?

Comment: @jmc Yes, in Neo4j 3.x, that's `conf/neo4j.conf`, and the entry is: `dbms.connector.http.address=0.0.0.0:7474`. `conf/neo4j-server.properties` is in Neo4j 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

To remotely access Neo4j installed on a Windows VM in Azure, these are the changes you'll need to make:

1. In the Azure portal, add TCP port 7474 to the Endpoints of your Windows VM
2. On your Windows VM, in the Windows Firewall Advances Security, add a new Inbound Rule for port 7474
3. Change the conf/neo4j.conf and uncomment this line:
   `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0`

*Note: In case you also want full access to Neo4j's browse interface including Bolt, then also add port 7687 both in the Azure Endpoints and the Windows Firewall.*